# SQL select merge multiple table result

Tags: sql, select

I want to run select query on multiple table and combine result. for example i want to merge Last_month server availability report with current_month availability report. I have two table Last_table1 and current_table1

```
Last_table1
===========
Hosts    Availability
Server1      99.99%
Server2      87.55%


Current_table1
==============
Hosts    Availability
Server1     78.00%
Server2     100.00%
```

I want to merge both table and need result like following. How do i write select query?

```
Hosts         Last       current
Server1      99.99%      78.00%
Server2      87.55%      100.00%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a `JOIN`, and display the proper columns in the proper places:

```
SELECT 
  L.Hosts, L.Availability AS Last, C.Availability AS Current
FROM 
  Last_Table1 L
INNER JOIN 
  Current_Table1 C
ON 
  C.Hosts = L.Hosts
```

Comment: Do you know how to merge three table ? I mean i have one more table to merge ?

Comment: Just add another INNER JOIN statement with another ON condition, and add the column. Look at how I added one table, and repeat it to add another one.