# MySQL Select from three tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I need write query get countries where have max money order by profession. Main table is: `used_money`

I have 3 tables: `used_money`, `users`, `groups`

I cannot post image see here:

[image]

I need get result like this:

```
Luxembourg    Hacker 200
Albania       Hacker 120
United States Boss    55
```

Comment: Look up how JOINs work.  As long as you have a unique key (like an ID)  that you can join them on, you can get your results.

Comment: Have you tried *ANYTHING*?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL select merge multiple table result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9217122/sql-select-merge-multiple-table-result)

Comment: Downvoted, no effort shown.

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs. I love art, but pictures are just so icky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this?

## QUERY:

```
SELECT country, profession, MAX(money) AS money 
FROM
(   SELECT u.country, g.profession, SUM(um.money) AS money
    FROM user_money um
    JOIN users u ON u.id = um.user_id
    JOIN groups g ON g.id = um.group_id
    GROUP BY g.profession, u.country
    ORDER BY um.money DESC
) t
GROUP BY country
ORDER BY money DESC
```

[SEE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/00750a/1)

## OUTPUT:

```
+---------------+------------+-------+
| country       | profession | money |
+---------------+------------+-------+
| Luxembourg    | Hacker     |  200  |
| Albania       | Hacker     |  120  |
| United States | Boss       |  55   |
+---------------+------------+-------+
```

Comment: `#1052 - Column 'money' in field list is ambiguous`

Comment: @jsphp edited: try again

Comment: @jsphp also look here for a sample showing http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/00750a/1

Comment: @jsphp no problem :) if you could mark the answer as accepted it would be appreciated :D